# jquery fade in adding inline style to span

Tags: jquery, css, browser

When using the fadeIn for a hidden span element, jquery adds `display:inline` to the inline styles. I understand why it does this because by default a span is a inline element although how do I set it to always `display:block;`

I have to use a `<span>` because:

- It is inside an `<a>`
- It needs to validate XHTML Strict
- Needs to work in IE6

Comment: If it's not break any design during animation - you can override style on complete callback `$('my element').fadeIn(100, function() { override styles here });`

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the only way sadly. I thought there may have been a option of some sort to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) instead of `.fadeIn()`, which (I *think*) won't change the `display` property while animating.